# MVC Razorview file upload to network path as part of form not submitting & file is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am using razorview and I trying to upload a file as part of a form to a network path. When I click on Submit nothing happens and my file input form field just goes blank. I debugged my code and found that the condition for checking if file is not blank returns false. So it doesn't go into that block of code at all. My code is as follows and I am not sure what is going wrong. Please help.

Create View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Serial", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Serial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Serial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Serial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SerialAttachment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SerialAttachment, new { type = "file", name = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SerialAttachment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

SerialController:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Serial,SerialAttachment")] SerialModel sm, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(networkpath), fname);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            db.SerialModel.Add(sm);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Upload failed";
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }

    return View(sm);
}
```

Model:

```
 public partial class SerialModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Serial { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string SerialAttachment { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Use HttpPostedFileBase prop instead string for socketDrawingAttachment

Comment: @arslanaybars How would it get saved in the db then ? I want to save the file name in the db so I am not sure what datatype it needs to be.

Comment: you could save uploaded file as byte[]

Comment: check this, if i were you i used that pattern : https://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/

Comment: @arslanaybars : Could you please point out what I am doing wrong. I have a column names SerialAttachment with varchar(250) datatype. And I want to save the filename without the full path in the table.